# Quick Access "Frequent Folders" Keeps Disappearing on Windows 10 1909

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-10-quick-access

For some time now, I have been having an annoying issue with the Quick Access page on Windows 10. My "Frequent Folders" list keeps disappearing, and my "Recent Files" list keeps changing its view mode to "Details." It looks like this (file names removed for privacy).

[image: Quick Access keeps reverting to this]

I have been able to temporarily work around it by opening the "Folder Options" panel from the "File" tab, switching to the "View" tab, and clicking "Reset Folders." This lets me restore the appearance of Quick Access to the way it should be, and the way I want it to be (again, file names removed for privacy). The problem is that after a while, it breaks again and reverts to what I showed in the first image. I have tried other things as well, including completely resetting Explorer and clearing the directories used for jumplists, but nothing works. I had this problem once before a few years ago and managed to fix it by deleting a specific registry key that I saw mentioned somewhere online, but I foolishly did not take note the key and have been unable to find it again.

[image: Normal appearance of Quick Access]

Does anyone know how I may fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Copy & paste this code into a **PowerShell** window. If it returns 5000, you've "maxed out" on saved folder views -- the OS has to delete a saved view every time it wants to save another one. Thus some folders seem to keep forgetting their views.

```
((gp "HKCU:\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU").Nodeslots).count
```

If you've hit 5000, you need to delete saved views by deleting the following two registry keys:

```
'HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\BagMRU'
'HKCU\Software\Classes\Local Settings\Software\Microsoft\Windows\Shell\Bags'
```

Sign out & back in or restart **Explorer** after deleting these keys.

---

If you haven't maxed out or after performing the above deletion, you can open **Quick Access** and use the **Apply to Folders** option on the same **View** tab in **Folder Options** where you found **Reset Folders**. **Quick Access** has its own *FolderType* and thus **Apply to Folders** will create a "custom" view template that seems to minimize "hiccups" with its unique view.

Comment: It appears that I have indeed hit 5,000! I've deleted the keys and restarted. Since this seems to be the solution, I shall mark as accepted! If I run in to any problems, I will follow up. Thanks for this!

Comment: You're welcome. You should be good. This is the time to turn off grouping in **Downloads** and use **Apply to FOlders** there as well to ensure Common Dialogs opened to **Downloads** don't group by Date.

Comment: I will definitely do that! I find the "Group By Date" thing in Downloads very annoying, but never bothered to change it.

Comment: About one month shy of a whole year since I asked this question, and the problem still hasn't been fixed properly by MS. I just ran in to it again today and had to redo your instructions.

Comment: Revisiting this post seems to have become an annual tradition for me, as I once again ran in to this issue again today. Even on Windows 11, this issue still persists. Fortunately, this workaround still seems to be useable.

Comment: Happy Anniversary!!! :D

Comment: Thank you!!! 